# Figure of the double integral

Tags: integration

Help me please draw a drawing for this task. I can not understand the geometric meaning of the double integral[image]

Comment: What is it you're having trouble with, specifically? Drawing the region $P$ in the plane? Visualising the integrand over this region? The concrete calculations that go into finding the value?

Comment: So the $P$ region is simply a rectangle right ? Let the $x$-axis be the $x_1$ variable and the $y$-axis the $x_2$ variable. Then the drawing is a rectangle with vertices at $(2,0), (2,2), (3,0), (3,2)$ and the domain of integration is the domain inside it (boundaries included). [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5Bx%2By,%7Bx,2,3%7D,%7By,0,2%7D%5D) is a plot of the function $x_1 + x_2$ on $P$.

Comment: 3-d model of this function. I want to look at the picture and understand that there is 7.

Comment: Perhaps going back to the basics will help here: what you did is calculate the *volume* of the 3-dimensional body formed by the rectangle on the $\;xy\,-$ plane and the surface $\;f(x_1,x_2):=x_1+x_2\;$ over it.

Comment: Many thanks to all!